# SQL Union to return most recent entry

Tags: sql, union

i have two tables

TableInitial

```
EnId  DateSeen
1     2013-05-01
4     2013-05-06
7     2013-05-01
13    2013-05-09
17    2013-05-09
```

TableFollowup

```
EnId  FId     DateSeen
1      1      2013-05-04
1      2      2013-05-05
1      3      2013-05-06
4      1      2013-05-09
4      2      2013-05-010
7      1      2013-05-02
13     1      2013-05-011
13     2      2013-05-014
13     3      2013-05-016
13     4      2013-05-019
```

I want to write a union for the above two table to out put the most recent entry for a paticular 'EnId' like the below.

Result table i want to be like the below

```
EnId   FId      DateSeen
1       3       2013-05-06
4       2       2013-05-010
7       1       2013-05-02
13      4       2013-05-019
17    <null>    2013-05-09
```

my sql code is

```
select EnId, FId, DateSeen  from tableFollowup
WHERE DateSeen =(Select MAX(DateSeen) FROM TableFollowup)

UNION
select EnId, '' AS FId, DateSeen  from tableInitial
GROUP BY EnId
```

but what i seem to get is the latest of the TableInitial and the latest of TableFollowup

```
EnId   FId      DateSeen
1    <null>     2013-05-01
1       3       2013-05-06
4    <null>     2013-05-06
4       2       2013-05-010
7    <null>     2013-05-01
7       1       2013-05-02
7       1       2013-05-02
13    <null>    2013-05-09
13      4       2013-05-019
17    <null>    2013-05-09
```

I think i have missed something, but not able to get this working.
thanks

Comment: is FId always incrementing?

Comment: Yes FId is always incrementing (unique)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Fid is always incrementing, you can use a solution like this:

```
SELECT EnID, MAX(FId), MAX(DateSeen)
FROM (
  SELECT EnID, Null AS FId, DateSeen
  FROM TableInitial
  UNION ALL
  SELECT EnId, FId, DateSeen
  FROM TableFollowup
) s
GROUP BY EnID
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/719e1/1). Or you can also use this as a subquery:

```
  SELECT EnID, Null AS FId, DateSeen
  FROM TableInitial
  UNION ALL
  SELECT EnId, MAX(FId), MAX(DateSeen)
  FROM TableFollowup
  GROUP BY EnID
```

(it might be faster)

Answer (score 0):

Tunning up your query:

```
select EnId, FId, DateSeen  from tableFollowup t1
WHERE DateSeen =(Select MAX(t2.DateSeen) FROM tableFollowup t2 WHERE t2.EnId = t1.EnId)
UNION
select EnId, '' AS FId, DateSeen  from tableInitial
Where EnId not in (Select enid from tableFollowup)
GROUP BY EnId
```

Comment: sorry, table2 is another name for tableFollowup, I have updated my original query.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the exact results as you requested.
It will eliminate any dubplicates as well.

```
SELECT MAX(DateSeen), MAX(FId), EnId FROM (select EnId, FId, DateSeen  from tableFollowup
UNION
select EnId, NULL AS FId, DateSeen from tableInitial) dt GROUP BY EnId
```